# Changes on Background NSManagedObjectContext not visible on Main, using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is a really bizarre issue, and I thought I understood Core Data.

I use a background context that has no parent.  Hooked right into the Persistent Store Coordinator.  I update objects on this background context then save it.  I listen to the `ContextDidSaveNotification` and merge those changes into my main thread context.  Those updated objects are not faults on the main thread as they are already used to populate table view cells.  So I would expect those changes to actually merge.  But they are not.

Without getting into the details of my data models, it suffices to say that an object has a property "`downloadState`".  Once the parsing work is done on the background thread, `downloadStateValue` (an enum) gets set to "3", which corresponds to 'completed'.

I subscribe to the `ContentWillSave` notification now to inspect what's going on.  I get this at the end of my parsing work:

```
2016-06-13 10:19:21.055 MyApp[29162:52855206] Going to save background context.
updated:{(
<QLUserPinnedCourse: 0x7fe195403c10> (entity: QLUserPinnedCourse; id: 0xd0000000002c0002 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLUserPinnedCourse/p11> ; data: {
  course = "0xd000000000dc0008 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLCourse/p55>";
  courseId = 2794;
  /* other fields redacted */
}),
<QLCourse: 0x7fe1954cded0> (entity: QLCourse; id: 0xd000000000dc0008 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLCourse/p55> ; data: {
 /* other fields redacted*/
 contentDownloadState = 3;
 courseId = 2794;
 pinnedUserData = "0xd0000000002c0002 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLUserPinnedCourse/p11>";
    })
```

The `NSFetchedResultsController` that is listenting to `QLUserPinnedCourse` objects gets the `delegate` calls, which triggers cell reloads in my tables.

The predicate is:

```
// Specify criteria for filtering which objects to fetch
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pinned == %@ && course.contentDownloadState IN %@",
                                  @YES,
                                  @[@(QLDownloadStateSucceeded), @(QLDownloadStateNotYetAttempted), @(QLDownloadStateFailed), @(QLDownloadStateIncomplete)]
                                  ];
```

Now when I get to the cell code, I have a `QLUserPinnedCourse` object to work with.  I set a breakpoint in the debugger and get:

```
(lldb) po userCourse.course
<QLCourse: 0x7fe19568f740> (entity: QLCourse; id: 0xd000000000dc0008 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLCourse/p55> ; data: {

    contentDownloadState = 1;
    courseId = 2794;
    pinnedUserData = "0xd0000000002c0002 <x-coredata://95821ADC-8A1F-4DAC-B20C-EDD8F8F413EA/QLUserPinnedCourse/p11>";
})
```

The question is, WHY is `contentDownloadState` not 3, but still 1 ??  I don't get it.

Shouldn't these changes have been merged??

Details as to my stack:

```
PSC -> Private Concurrent (saving context) -> Main Thread context

PSC -> Private Concurrent (import context)
```

ContextDidSave:
if the context was an import context, merge changes into both contexts above:

```
_contextSaveObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                                             object:nil
                                                                              queue:nil
                                                                         usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note)
                            {
                                NSManagedObjectContext *contextSaved = note.object;
                                NSManagedObjectContext *moc = weakself.mainQueueContext;

                                // basically, if this was a background worker thread

                                DDLogDebug(@"updatedObjects:%@", note.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]);

                                if ([contextSaved.userInfo[CoreDataUserInfoKeyIsWorkerContext] boolValue])
                                {
                                    [weakself.privateSavingContext performBlock:^(){

                                        for (NSManagedObject *object in note.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
                                            [[weakself.privateSavingContext objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
                                        }

                                        [weakself.privateSavingContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];

                                        [moc performBlock:^(){

                                            for (NSManagedObject *object in note.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
                                                [[moc objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
                                            }

                                            [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];


                                        }];
                                    }];
                                }
                            }];
```

Note that I'm asking the `userCourse`.course object for its attribute, although my FRC is interested in `QLUserPinnedCourse` objects.  I thought because I specify a keypath in the predicate that relates to a `QLCourse` object, these changes are refreshed.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the download state?

Comment: it was done inside a performBlockAndWait: call on the main thread context, at the end of which it tells it to save up to the PSC.  The code itself isn't helpful as you'd need to know more of my Core Data controller.  That code has been proven to work just fine.   Also, SO needs to allow fixedFont markup in comments!!

Could it be a merge policy problem?  i think I set these properties on the MT after the worker context was created. and that worker never merged that update.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk of Core Data.  You actually need to re-fault objects in the main context which were updated by the save operation.

Here's an example in Swift:

```
mainContext.performBlock {
    let updatedObjects : Set<NSManagedObject> = notification.userInfo![NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as! Set<NSManagedObject>

    for obj in updatedObjects {
        self.mainContext.objectWithID(obj.objectID).willAccessValueForKey(nil)
    }

    self.mainContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
}
```

The main part is the call to `willAccessValueForKey:nil`, which causes the object to be marked as a fault.  This will cause `NSFetchedResultsController`s in the main context to fire.

Comment: is it because I'm looking at an object that is a to-one relationship?  so it doesn't get refreshed?  The NSFetchedResultsController "doesn't care about it" ?

Comment: the delegate methods of the NSFetchedResultsController do fire.  It just seems like the related object of type QLCourse is stale?

Comment: An `NSFetchedResultsController` will not fire for property changes on a related object.  Only changing the relationship itself triggers a change.  What I do in my own code is to set the relationship to itself (current value, e.g. `obj.relationship = obj.relationship`) to force FRCs to trigger.

Comment: As I've stated a few times already, the FRC delegate DOES fire.  It's part of a batch update that includes the parent object.

Comment: I don't get it, then.  What's the problem?  My answer helps with the objects not updating, my comment helps with the child property not triggering the FRC.  If one isn't the issue, the other is.

Comment: I dont' mean to be rude, but did you read the post?  Not skim it, but read it.  It gives you insight into my thought process.  Maybe I've missed something.

The objects to be updated / merged to the main thread context and their properties are listed.  They are not the same values when I use that object via the main thread.  Which suggests they're not merging / refreshing / something.  But if I knew the exact problem I wouldn't be here, would I... :)

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is exactly the quirk I mentioned in my answer.  Did you try the code I posted (translated to ObjC, if necessary)?

Comment: yes I did.  It didn't result in anything propagating to the objects managed by FRC's memory cache.  I also tried setting the following in the fetchRequest: 
```
 fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"course"];
        fetchRequest.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = YES;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114513/discussion-between-avi-and-horseshoe7).

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution but I can't tell you why it works.

The problem I suppose is that I would have a method 'start downloading content' and I would update the property `contentDownloadState` on the main thread context to 'incomplete/downloading', then proceed to get all the content.

All the rest of the work was done on a background thread context.  When finished I updated that value with 'succeeded'.  It wasn't merging that change.  I have no idea why.

Once I decided to do everything on the worker context.  i.e. change its value then save the context to disk, the changes, ALL the changes were propagating.

So in the end I solved it, but really don't understand the problem.